# Refresh of html sidebar and dropdown menu Javascript function error

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am new to html & javascript and have been following along with an online course regarding a leaflet webmap application.

I have a drop down menu in my sidebar which enables the user to filter the locations by category, and a function that does a refresh of the sidebar and dropdown menu after every filter selection and is called at the beginning when the web application starts as well.

When I run my index.html code in Chrome locally, the console states an error with the html header tag in my refreshCCP function (**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**), but cannot see a problem with it:

```
$("#side_panel").html("<h1 class='text-center'>Search Panel</h1>
```

The above line of code is found at the bottom of the script area in the refreshCCP function

All HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Router</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.0/dist/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
    <style>
        #header {
            height: 85px;
            background-color:darkgoldenrod;
        }
        #mapdiv {
            height: 650px;
            background-color:salmon;
        }
        #side_panel {
            height: 650px;
            background-color:beige;
        }
        #footer {
            height: 85px;
            background-color:darkgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
       <body>
        <div id="header" class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">CCP Finder</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="side_panel" class="col-md-3"> //
            <h1 class="text-center">Search Panel</h1>
        <!-- dropdown filter box -->
        <select id = "filter" class="form-control">
            <option value="All">All CCP</option>
            <option value="ex1">ex1 CCP</option>
            <option value="ex2">ex2 CCP</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="mapdiv" class="col-md-9"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="col-md-12">
            <h4 id="map_coords" class="text-center">Latitude:53.4 Longitude: -113.7 Zoom Level: 10.5</h4>
            <h4 class="text-center">&copy;2022 <a href="xxxxx">xxxx</a>
            </h4>                                    
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var mymap = L.map('mapdiv')
            mymap.setView([53.4, -113.7], 10.5);
            
            var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
            mymap.addLayer(backgroundLayer);  
                   
            var lyrCCP;
            <!-- Refresh sidepanel and filter dropdown function -->
            refreshCCP();
            
                mymap.on('mousemove', function(e){
                var str = "Latititude: "+e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5)+" Longitude: "+e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5)+" Zoom Level: "+mymap.getZoom();
                $("#map_coords").html(str);
            });
           <!-- Refresh sidepanel and filter dropdown function -->
            function refreshCCP(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'load_ccp.php',
                    type: 'POST',                    
                    data:{filter:$("#filter").val()},
                    success:function(response){
                if (lyrCCP) {
                    mymap.removeLayer(lyrCCP);
                    $("#side_panel").html("<h1 class='text-center'>Search Panel</h1>
                    <select id='filter' class = 'form-control'>
                    <option value='All'>All CCP</option>
                    <option value='ex1'>ex1 CCP</option>
                    <option value='ex2'>ex2 CCP</option>
                </select>");
                };
                lyrCCP=L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
                    var str = "<hr>CCP Number:<h4>"+feature.properties.cp_no+"</h4>";
                    str += "<hr>River Name: <h4>"+feature.properties.river+"</h4>";
                    str += "<img src='img/"+feature.properties.tactic+"' width = '200px'></img>";
                    return L.circleMarker(latlng).bindPopup(str);
                }});
                lyrCCP.addTo(mymap);
                mymap.fitBounds(lyrCCP.getBounds());
            }});
                
        $("#filter").change(function(){
            refreshCCP();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get it to work, you need to send a template literal instead of a string by using the grave character:

```
$("#side_panel").html(
    `<h1 class='text-center'>Search Panel</h1>
     <select id='filter' class = 'form-control'>
         <option value='All'>All CCP</option>
         <option value='ex1'>ex1 CCP</option>
         <option value='ex2'>ex2 CCP</option>
     </select>`);
```

Comment: Fixing that line of code revealed that there is an error somewhere else. The error you were getting before was hiding it.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a problem with my filter dropdown menu call.  I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON"